# MeteorJS Angular 4 component with stylus include

Tags: angular, meteor, stylus

I am happily writing Angular 4 components in a new MeteorJS Project. With Meteor and Stylus I think it is common to import all your stylus files in a main.styl which is then turned into a `merged-stylesheets.css` in your temp build folder.

This works fine. However, to make the components easily reusable I have to stylus files with the component typescript files and templates. However, I cannot import the stylus file in the component file like I could with a CSS file when using Webpack for exmaple.

Is there anyway to NOT import the files globally in the `main.styl` but just in the component file itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-form-example',
  templateUrl: './input-form-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-form-example.component.css']
})
```

use "styleUrls" 
or
    "styles:[]"

Comment: I am using Stylus preprocessor. I am not using CSS so I can't use the styleUrls. My CSS is concatenated in the build folder of Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can limit your style to component file only using View Encapsulation.

View encapsulation defines whether the template and styles defined within the component can affect the whole application or vice versa. Angular provides three encapsulation strategies:

1. `Emulated` (default) - styles from main HTML propagate to the
   component. Styles defined in this component's `@Component` decorator
   are scoped to this component only.
2. `Native` - styles from main HTML do not propagate to the component.
   Styles defined in this component's `@Component` decorator are scoped
   to this component only.
3. `None` - styles from the component propagate back to the main HTML and
   therefore are visible to all components on the page. Be careful with
   apps that have None and Native components in the application. All
   components with None encapsulation will have their styles duplicated
   in all components with Native encapsulation.

@Component({
// ...

encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,

styles: [

// ...
   ]
  })

http://plnkr.co/edit/E5Hb6B5dRN0llz3JuO57?p=preview

hope this will help you :)

Comment: Not sure If I made it clear enough that I am using a separate STYLUS file in my component folder which in Meteor, I need to import at the root level. It would be nice if it is somehow possible to include that stylus file into the component only. So in current MeteorJS setup the stylus will be converted to a concatenated CSS file that sits in the root. If it was a CSS file I could import it directly into the component.

Comment: I never used STYLUS but I think it will be like sass which we preprocess.. to include a style only in a component use viewEncapsulation.Native and you need some way that convert your STYLUS to CSS when we do ng serve in angular cli. There is also option to choose default style file type in angular cli. Change you app setting in angularcli.json according to that. If you use viewencapsulation native then that component style file will apply to that component only.

Comment: I will have a look at the docs and have play. Thanks for your suggestion.